# Multi-threaded processing in Python 3 on Windows

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a data processing task written in Python that reads through a huge CSV file using the Python CSV reader, validates the data in each column, then writes each line to a new file in a different format.  The data is then bulk loaded into a database.  This creation of the new CSV takes around 60 minutes, while the duration of the load is insignificant.

I would like to speed up the creation of the CSV, and as the task is CPU bound, the obvious solution would be to try to utilize all 12 of the server's cores and process sections of the file in parallel.

I have looked at what is available here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing, and in particular at the Parallel Python library, which seems to be exactly what I need (http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/17/31/) but none of them seem to work with Python 3 / Windows.

Does anyone know of a parallel processing framework that would meet my needs, or any other advice on the best way to achieve what I am trying to do?  I am looking for something flexible, while hopefully avoiding having to re-invent the wheel or deal with messy details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use threading, but then you might end up with threads locking in the GIL. And you'd have to worry about locking.

Therefore I's suggest using the built-in [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module, specifically the "[Pool](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)" object. By default, a Pool will create as much worker processes as your machine has cores.

In the main process, create a Pool of workers. You can then e.g use `Pool.map_async()` or `Pool.imap()` to apply a function to all your data, provided it is in iterable form. The Pool object keeps track of the messy details for you.